# What is the difference between withCriteria and CreateCriteria in Grails?

Tags: grails

What is their difference and why and where we need to use them,i think it seems like they have no difference at all to me ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth adding what I just came across in the grails documentation for `createCriteria()`.

> Because that query includes pagination parameters (max and offset), this will return a PagedResultList which has a getTotalCount() method to return the total number of matching records for pagination. Two queries are still run, but they are run for you and the results and total count are combined in the PagedResultList.

[Source](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

This means you can use `getTotalCount()` without having to initiate the call (it's made for you). This is very helpful. The example documentation shows:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c.list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
    like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
    and {
        between("balance", 500, 1000)
        eq("branch", "London")
    }
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
println "Rendering ${results.size()} Accounts of ${results.totalCount}"
```

This capability is *not* available when using `withCriteria()`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write query for from/to date using above BETWEEN clause?

Comment: @VVB Your question would be better suited as a new stackoverflow question, rather than including it here as a comment.

Answer (score 11):

`withCriteria { ... }` is essentially shorthand for `createCriteria().list { ... }`. If you need to use any of the other criteria methods (get, count, ...) or pass pagination parameters to `list` then you have to use the long-hand form.

```
SomeDomain.createCriteria().list(max:10, offset:50) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write query for from/to date using BETWEEN clause?

Comment: @VVB if you can't get it working from the information at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html then you'd be better off asking this as a SO question in its own right, as it's not really related to the subject of this question.

Comment: Alright @IanRoberts I am going to post new question please check it

Comment: @IanRoberts I just posted new question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604309/how-to-write-between-clause-for-from-to-dates-for-createcriteria-in-grails Can you please answer it so I can up vote & accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Example of **`createCriteria()`**:

```
def criteria = OfferCredit.createCriteria {
    offer {
        eq('status', LeverageUtils.ACTIVE_STATUS)
        ge('expirationDate', new Date())
    }
    user {
        eq('userId', userId)
    }
    eq('status', LeverageUtils.ACTIVE_STATUS)
    order('creationDate', 'asc')
}

criteria.list()
```

---

Example of **`withCriteria()`**:

```
List<Supermarket> results = Supermarket.withCriteria {
    like("sp_street", params.street)
    productSupermarket {
         product {
            idEq(params.product)
        }
        // or just eq('product', someProduct)
    }
    maxResults(10)
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for the examples you gave. It is seems that createCritera apply the criteria parameters after finding the domain objects and withCriteria -apply query parameters first and do domin object finding next. isn't it?

Comment: Yes! If you use createCriteria, you can do multiple operations like list and more. But, if you use 'withCriteria', the default operation is list. (You cannot do any other operation).

Answer (score 4):

withCriteria executes and returns the list.  It provides a closure using which you can customize the criteria before it gets executed.

createCriteria just creates a criteria object which you can modify and then explicitly call the list method to execute.

If criteria is simple or if it is defined in a single place it is better to use withCriteria.

If you need to pass the criteria around (create it in one function and pass it to others) createCriteria would be better.  I think withCriteria support is limited.

Comment: can you give examples please ?

Answer (score 2):

withCriteria ->

Purpose -> Allows inline execution of Criteria queries.
If no matching records are found, an empty List is returned.

If a projection is specified:

```
returns a single value if it only contains one field
a List in case there are multiple fields in the projection
```