# How to write between clause for from & to dates for createCriteria in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to fetch results between 2 dates using following code.

```
def c = TestCase.createCriteria()
resultss = c.list {
    like("testStatus", "Dummy")
    and {
        between("testTime", date1, date2)
    }
    order('testified','desc')
}
```

Here I want to select From Date and To Date like below

```
FROM DATE : '2014-11-07 12:14:03'(date1)
TO DATE   : '2015-01-09 08:14:12'(date2)
```

I tried a lot but no luck to get it run.

Can anybody please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Obvious questions first - the `testTime` property, and the `date1` and `date2` variables are all the same type (`java.util.Date`)?  And have you tried moving the `like` inside the `and` block (an `and` with only one member doesn't make much sense)?

Comment: Yes testime,date1,date2 are of the same data type which Date

Comment: And second is I tried removing like clause & putting it in and clause but still not getting result

Comment: Also Is there any exception you are getting? It will be helpful if you post your domain as well.

Comment: No I am not getting any exception but this is giving me 0 number of rows which I displayed on console

Comment: there's not much to break here, I can only expect that it's just data that fails it, you can try `TestCase.list().findAll { it.testTime >= date1 && it.testTime < date2 /* && it.testStatus == 'Dummy' */ }`  and see if it returns anything ?

Comment: @VBB then maybe you would care to elaborate on your question.  Please provide a complete example of the things you want to achieve and provide a solid error-case for "i tried a lot but no luck to get it run"

Answer (score 1):

the `and` there is odd;  first of all and is the default anyway.  and if you want to be explicit, then put the statements into the and block:

```
and {
    like("testStatus", "Dummy")
    between("testTime", date1, date2)
}
```

or just

```
like("testStatus", "Dummy")
between("testTime", date1, date2)
```